# Kings' Chess Harem

Tags: chess, optimization, checkerboard

Pursueing these two related puzzles, [Chess Bloodshed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104207/chess-bloodshed) and [Devouring Nobility](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104174/51928) I create for you Kings' Chess Harem where you have to find, with the minimum number of moves, a legal game where all pawns get promoted to a Queen.

Comment: OMG I was just about to post EXACTLY the same puzzle!!! Great minds think alike.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky hahaha, a pleasure to share these ideas with you :)

Comment: Related (but not the same, since this puzzle doesn't say ananything about the original queens): https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4128/7297

Comment: Henry VIII Queens ok? I.e. after being promoted do they have to survive til the end of the game?

Comment: @PaulPanzer, the puzzle doesn't say anything about the Queens or the original ones. They can survive or not as long as the 16 pawns get promoted :)

Comment: Does it still count as an adequate harem if the promoted queens are subsequently fed to the opposing pawns?

Comment: @Bass yes! Actually, maybe the term harem isn't the best one :) Do you have any ideas of other noun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 46 moves per side is possible

> 1. a4 h5 2. Ra3 Rh6 3. g4 b5 4. g5 b4 5. gxh6 bxa3 6. b4 g5 7. b5 g4 8. b6 g3 9. b7 g2 10. bxa8=Q gxh1=Q 11. h7 a2 12. h8=Q a1=Q 13. Qb2 Qb7 14. a5 c5 15. a6 c4 16. axb7 c3 17. bxc8=Q cxb2 18. c4 bxc1=Q 19. c5 a5 20. c6 a4 21. c7 a3 22. cxb8=Q a2 23. Qc4 Qg7 24. d4 Qcg5 25. e4 Nf6 26. e5 h4 27. Qg2 h3 28. exf6 hxg2 29. fxg7 f5 30. f4 d5 31. fxg5 dxc4 32. g8=Q c3 33. g6 c2 34. d5 c1=Q 35. d6 e5 36. h4 e4 37. h5 Qc7 38. dxc7 e3 39. c8=Q e2 40. Qgd5 f4 41. g7 f3 42. h6 f2+ 43. Kd2 gxf1=Q 44. h7 fxg1=Q 45. g8=Q axb1=Q 46. h8=Q e1=Q+

> Note that 80 pawn moves, 8 other moves for passing by piece capture, and some moves to handle check are needed, so 44 moves per side is not possible

> [Try it online!](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_h5_Ra3_Rh6_g4_b5_g5_b4_gxh6_bxa3_b4_g5_b5_g4_b6_g3_b7_g2_bxa8ZQ_gxh1ZQ_h7_a2_h8ZQ_a1ZQ_Qb2_Qb7_a5_c5_a6_c4_axb7_c3_bxc8ZQ_cxb2_c4_bxc1ZQ_c5_a5_c6_a4_c7_a3_cxb8ZQ_a2_Qc4_Qg7_d4_Qcg5_e4_Nf6_e5_h4_Qg2_h3_exf6_hxg2_fxg7_f5_f4_d5_fxg5_dxc4_g8ZQ_c3_g6_c2_d5_c1ZQ_d6_e5_h4_e4_h5_Qc7_dxc7_e3_c8ZQ_e2_Qgd5_f4_g7_f3_h6_f2*_Kd2_gxf1ZQ_h7_fxg1ZQ_g8ZQ_axb1ZQ_h8ZQ_e1ZQ*)